# Запись и отправка звука в html

Tags: html, html-form, звукозапись

Если на мобильном открыть сайт с формой, через которую нужно передать файл, и нажать в этой форме "выбрать файл", мы можем видеть кнопку снятия фотографии с камеры телефона. Реализовано ли что либо подобное для записи и передачи звука с системного микрофона?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17786351/using-html5-to-capture-microphone-input-on-mobile-chrome http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27846392/access-microphone-from-a-browser-javascript

Answer (score 0):

По идеи можно. Но на это нужно разрешение системы. Обычно, при первом запуске подобного диалогового окна андроид спрашивает, разрешить ли получение данных с тех или иных ресурсов (камера, микрофон). Вы до этого могли в диалоговом окне поставить галочку "Не спрашивать больше". Покопайтесь в настройках, наверняка найдете...

Comment: В вопросе говорится несколько не об этом. Хотя в принципе возможный вариант.